# Display actual value if a test fails

Tags: python, python-unittest

Say I have a test like this:

```
self.assertTrue( car.color == 'blue')
```

I run it with

```
nosetests test_car.py -x -v --stop
```

If it fails, I would like it to print out the actual value of car.color. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's where you need to use `self.assertEqual(car.color, 'blue')`. `assertTrue` is better for checking boolean properties or expressions that aren't simple equality.

Comment: Also you can specify a message after e.g. assertTrue(expression, 'message here') or self.assertEqual(car.color, 'blue', 'colors are not the same')